# Label Title cut when changing text font (Open Motif 2.3.1)

Tags: c, linux, motif

I am trying to solve a problem on a software. I have two windows created with Motif library. 
The first window contains 5 buttons (Font 1, 2, 3, 4, Exit), choosing a font affects the text of the other window ("Unacknowledged Updates"). 
**When the second window text is in font 1, and we click on the font 4 or font 3 button, the result consists in displaying a text label cut on the second window.**

I have written a prototype to reproduce the bug using the same way of coding and initializing widgets. However, I can not reproduce the bug yet. The thing is, the way of how callbacks are managed in my prototype is far more simple than in the original code which uses Xevent sent to X server.

You can find two screenshots displaying the problem following the link: 
[***---Screenshots---***](http://www.hostingpics.net/viewer.php?id=592172screenshot14.jpg)

You will find the prototype code following this link : [***---here---***](http://pastebin.com/JR7eFVDq)

The line to compile : gcc mmm_window.c -lX11 -lXm -lXt -o mmm_window

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by forcing redraw of 3 XmForm.

Comment: How does one do this?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the problem would come from the size of my label (width, height) which does not adapt when changing fonts. I have tried to set XmNrecomputeSize to true on the concerned widget but it did not help. I keep on searching...